# how to do body painting in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, texture

I have photo of a person and a texture. I'd like paint this body with this texture. How can I do it in photoshop?

An example : http://www.ibackgroundz.com/pics/d/o/download-body-painting-24-wallpaper-a-e-ibackgroundz.com.jpg
Basically I want to know how to apply a texture over body.

Comment: Welcome to GD.  While not an exact duplicate, another question has a very similar request and may be worth taking a look at:  http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/4871/render-graphic-on-a-t-shirt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image you linked to is actually paint on a body and not a photo alteration.

However, to do this with Photoshop, you need to be come acquainted with Displacement Maps. Displacement Maps use a greyscale image as a bump map and allow you to add the "bump" appearance to an otherwise flat image.

Here are a few displacement map tutorial via Google:

- [createoverflow.com](http://creativeoverflow.net/displacement-effect-tutorial-in-photoshop/)
- [Computerarts.co.uk](http://www.computerarts.co.uk/tutorials/displacement-effects)
- [Layers Magazine](http://layersmagazine.com/displacement-maps-for-graphics-in-photoshop-cs4.html)
- [scribd.com](http://www.scribd.com/doc/4301/Photoshop-Tutorial-Displacement-Maps)
- [Photoshopessentials.com](http://www.photoshopessentials.com/photo-effects/texture-map/)